# Displaying a UIImageview in a UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm making an app where I have a UICollectionView and I want some collectionviewcells to display an image. What should I do in my code for the UIImageViews to show up? Aside from that, what should I do for my collectionviewcells to show up as well? I looked to a lot of places on the internet and nothing has worked. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use PSTCollectionView for showing the collectionview in your view. Download the code and play with it. Read readme.txt for additional information.

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView/commit/f8a9717eca9d32d5085154b1c6d58b4c59961a91)

Hope this will help you a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't really help me. I couldn't really find what I needed in here.